# Better way to select specific elements with a specific data-attribute in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to select all `a, button, input[type="submit"]` elements that also had a `data-type` attribute.

Will be the better, faster and/or simpler solution?

My current solution: `$('a[data-type], button[data-type], input[type="submit"][data-type]');`

When all elements are selected, i will bind a click event to them.

I was thinking about something like `$('a, button, input[type="submit"]').on('click', '[data-type]', function () { ...` but this is not working, for sure. ;) But maybe there is something similar, i don't know.

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution?

Comment: If all the elements have a shared ancestor, you could bind a single handler and just inspect the type there.

Comment: You're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @Mathletics, the current solution is fine but thought i can be simplified.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer what do you mean?

Comment: Your question asks about the "Fastest way", yet your post content says what you tried is broken. You might want to solve the issue of why it's broken in the first place before looking for the fastest/simplest.

Comment: Ok, i've updated the question. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

First tag before ".on" is not multiple tag.

You can do :

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "[data-type]", function() {
  ...
});
```

I tested it, it works !

or more precisely :

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", 
                "a[data-type], button[data-type], etc", 
                function() { 
                  ... 
              });
```

Comment: "First tag before ".on" is not multiple tag." That's no true. You can definitely pass multiple selectors to the jQuery function.

Comment: Good idea, i will try it. Thanks. :)